# How to call json object from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here is my script:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "Get", 
    url: "Sample.js",
    datatype: 'json', 
    data: JSON.stringify({ key:key }), 
    success: function (data) { 
        var sample = data.name; 
        $("#html").html(sample); 
    }, 
    error: function () {
        alert("Error"); 
    }
});
```

This is my `Sample.js` file:

```
{ "name": "user" }
```

When I run this code I get a blank screen. This is my script using `getJSON()`:

```
$.getJSON("Sample.js", function (data) { 
    var sample = data.name; 
    $("#html").html(sample); 
})
```

This produces "user" perfectly. What is the problem with `$.ajax` code?

Comment: What is `data: JSON.stringify({ key:key })`? Check the console for errors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is datatype: 'json', data: JSON.stringify({key:key }) is correct? i am new to this concepts?

Comment: What is the `key` variable you are passing over?

Comment: I believe the `data: JSON.stringify({key:key})` is the data you are passing to the `Sample.js` file have you tried to parse the JSON in the success function? i.e. `JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: jQuery processes data by itself, unsless you tell it not to using `processData: false`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i dont know the syntax to convert json object to string. i referred net and get this as the syntax.

Comment: I found syntax error initially and i given answer. Check whether that helps you

Comment: @Murali I TRIED,IT COMES THE SAME RESULT.

Comment: @sms Remove JSON.Stringify also

Comment: i removed @Murali... it still remains the same.

Comment: @sms, changing from `Get` to `GET`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getJSON` version your don't send any data. Could this be the reason why that works? To me it looks like this could be sth. on the server side that delivers an empty JSON object when you pass the key parameter.

Comment: i dont need to pass any data. i just want get from Sample.js.

Comment: then remove the ```data``` line, that worked just fine for me (jQuery v1.10.2)

Comment: if you are still facing that issue you could place a breakpoint at the beginning of the ```success``` function and have a look on what is returned... to me the descriptor ```#html``` looks suspicious. if there is no element with the id ```html``` you might want to try ```html``` (without the hash) instead

Comment: i have a div with id html.After taking data out it is working fine. thank you all.

Comment: but how to get json object from .aspx page... i.e how to declare in .aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

As the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) states:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

Try modifying the `dataType` param.

Comment: what to put as data in data:data.

Comment: You put only `{ key : key }` as data, jQuery stringifies it by default.

Comment: The `dataType` parameter relates to the _response_, not the _request_.

Comment: Well that's exactly the issue. If the `dataType` isn't set to `json`, jQuery doesn't know it receives a JSON response, so it doesn't know how to parse it. That's why when the OP uses `$.getJSON()` everything works as expected.

Comment: @AndreiHorak yes,it still doesn't work. in the qstn itself i used dataType:"json"...

Comment: You still have `datatype` instead of `dataType`.

Answer (score 0):

change your `datatype` to `dataType`. Its case sensitive. Refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Remove JSON.Stringify and change `Get` to `GET`

```
$.ajax(
   { type: "GET", 
     url: "Sample.js", 
     dataType: "json",
     data: {key:key }, 
     success: function (data) 
      { var sample = data.name; $("#html").html(sample); }, 
     error: function () { alert("Error"); }}
);
```